# Why is theMethod on Object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, loops, class, instantiation

I'm trying to call a method `walkDown(y,id){}` on my object `game` and it returns undefined. The similar method `walkUp(y,id){}` works as intended. Here is the code:

```
class Game {
    constructor(row,col,players) {
        this.players = players;  
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.gameBoard=[];
          for (let i=0; i<row; i++){
            this.gameBoard[i] =[];
              for (let y =0; y<col; y++){
                  this.gameBoard[i][y] = 0;
              }
          }
      }

  placing(id){
    var place = true;
    while(place){
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
      if (this.gameBoard[y][x] === 0){
        this.gameBoard[y][x] = this.players[id];
      place = false;
      } //if finish
    } // while finish
  }// function placing finish



  walkDown(y,id){
    for(var k = 0; k < this.gameBoard.length; k++){
      for(var m = 0; m < this.gameBoard[k].length; m++){
        if(this.gameBoard[k][m]===this.players[id]){
          this.gameBoard[k][m] = 0;
          this.gameBoard[k+y][m]= this.players[id];
        }
      }
    } 
  } 

  walkUp(y,id){
    for(var k = 0; k < this.gameBoard.length; k++){
      for(var m = 0; m < this.gameBoard[k].length; m++){
        if(this.gameBoard[k][m]===this.players[id]){
          this.gameBoard[k][m] = 0;
          this.gameBoard[k-y][m]= this.players[id];
        }
      }
    }
  } 

}// Class Game finish

class Player{
  constructor(id){
  this.id = id;
  }
}

const game = new Game(10,10,[new Player(0), new Player(1)]);
game.placing(0);
game.placing(1);

// game.walkUp(1,0); will work
// game.walkDown(1,0); throws an error
```

The undefined comes from this line of code `this.gameBoard[k+y][m]= this.players[id]`. However as mentioned above the method `walkUp(y,id){}` with the similar line of code `this.gameBoard[k-y][m]= this.players[id]` presents the required result.

What am I doing wrong here? Link to the code
https://jsbin.com/kizateh/edit?js,console

Comment: I suppose ```k + y``` returns 10 at last iteration, that is unreachable

Comment: in walkdown k goes upto `this.gameBoard.length` and `this.gameBoard[k+y]` will most certainly result in an index overflow. You need to bounds check your array before performing any operation on it

Comment: I will provide verification later on the code. But assuming the k is equal to anything up to 7, why will it throw the error? e.g this.gameBoard[5+1][2]= this.players[id]